# Audio off on charging Java Android

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android and want to make some code to shut down audio, ringer and notifications if an Android device is on the charger.

Up till now I came this far:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private AudioManager audioManager;

private int currentRingerVolume;
private int currentNotificationVolume;
private int currentAudioVolume;

// stream audio just to be sure if some SIP app uses Audio for ringer in stead of Ringer

private boolean silenceMode = false;
private boolean appStart = true;

public void silence() {

    if (!silenceMode) {
        currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        currentNotificationVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        currentAudioVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, 0);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);

        silenceMode = true;
    }
}

public void oldVolume() {

    if (silenceMode) {

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, currentRingerVolume, 0);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, currentNotificationVolume, 0);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentAudioVolume, 0);

        silenceMode = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (appStart) {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        appStart = false;
    }
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
            if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC) {
                silence();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Silence on AC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB) {
                silence();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Silence on USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (plugged == 0) {
                oldVolume();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Old Volume on Battery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


}
```

}

This works fine as long as you don't rotate the screen, when you rotate your screen as it is on charge, it does not turn back to the old volume state.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen, onDestroy() is being called, then onCreate() is being called, and it is evaluating oldVolume as the same volume that the application set the phone to, which is silent. you will need to override onDestroy() to save the oldVolume and pass it to the new instance of your application when the screen rotates